# React: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') when trying to use react-bootstrap container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, containers, react-bootstrap

As stated in the title I am trying to create a layout component but using any react-bootstrap components seems to give me errors. In this case, using  I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

The code for this Layout component is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const Layout = (props) => (
    <Container>
        {props.children}
    </Container>
    )
```

And this is being called from App.js below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';

import './custom.css'

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Switch>
                <Router>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                </Router>
            </Switch>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Replacing the container tags with div renders as expected but any use of react-bootstrap causes the useContext error.

Comment: Which version of react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: @IgorGonak 5.2.0

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I seem to (occasionally) get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

*Router* must be above *Switch*:

```
<Router>
    <Layout>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    </Layout>
</Router>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-zeh-r3vvl4

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't stopped the error from occurring, even adding just a button to app.js causes the described problem

Comment: But you see that my codesandbox works? Where is the difference between sandbox and your code?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason of such error is to have *multiple* versions of `react`. This can be checked by your package manager: `npm why react` / `yarn why react`. Or a shell command like `find . -name react`.

A second (and unintended) version of react could be introduced as transitive dependency, or from some tricky package resolution process.

How to eliminate multiple versions depend on the package manager you use. npm has `package.json overrides` and `npm dedup`, yarn has `resolutions`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you import it.

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error, I fixed that by updating my bootstrap version.