# Uncaught typeError: cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext' when executing even basic MaterialUI components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is the error message:

ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86566:25)
at useTheme (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51518:52).....

The basic component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export function Mappbar() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
      <Button variant="text">Text</Button>
      <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
      <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Tried all the solutions in this thread:
[React: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') when trying to use react-bootstrap container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71846286/react-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usecontext-when-try/71847620#71847620)

including npm dedup but not resolved.

Comment: I don't see any error using this link to [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bird-fsboi7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you add more context to the question or create a reproducible code in any online editor and share